# How to Stream from flutter application and receive on another flutter application?

Tags: flutter, webrtc, http-live-streaming, rtsp, rtmp

Flutter is new to me. I am planning to create 2 applications. One app (admin) is used to make a live stream (both from the camera and from a file), while another app is used to display the live video. Please assist me. how to do these things. any package is available? what kind of streaming protocol will use

Comment: you can check `webrtc` , `agora-webrtc` plugin on pub.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.